Proof explanation: A nonempty open set in $\Bbb R$ is the union of countable family of pairwise disjoint open intervals.
A nonempty open set in $\Bbb R$ is the union of countable family of pairwise disjoint open intervals.
The proof given is as follows:
Let $U\subseteq \Bbb R$ be open and $x\in U.$ There exists an open interval  $J$ such that $x\in J\subseteq U.$ Let $J_x$ denote the union of all open intervals that contain $x$ and contained in $U.$ Then $J_x$ is open. It is an interval since $x$ is common to all the intervals that constitute $J_x.$ (Why?) Given $x,y\in U,$ we show that $J_x$ and $J_y$ are either identical or disjoint. Define an equivalence relation on $U$ saying that $x\tilde y$ if $J_x = J_y.$ Using this,
we can write $U$ as the union of a family, say, $\{J_i:i\in I\}$ of pairwise disjoint open intervals. Choose one rational number $r_i\in J_i$ from each interval of this family. Then for $i\neq j,$ $i,j\in I, r_i\neq r_j$ since $J_i\cap J_j=\emptyset.$ We thus have a one-one map $i\to r_i$ from $I$ into $\Bbb Q.$ Thus, $I$ is countable.

I have a few questions regarding the above proof. In the part where they say,

Let $U\subseteq \Bbb R$ be open and $x\in U.$ There exists an open interval  $J$ such that $x\in J\subseteq U.$ Let $J_x$ denote the union of all open intervals that contain $x$ and contained in $U.$

Well, won't $J_x$ be precisely equal to $U$? This is because, $U$ is the largest subset of $U$ itself that contains $x.$ We also note that $x$ is arbitrary. So, given $x,y\in U$ we have, $J_x=J_y=U.$
Next, they mention,

we can write $U$ as the union of a family, say, $\{J_i:i\in I\}$ of pairwise disjoint open intervals.

But, the set $\{J_i:i\in I\}$ is equal to $U.$ (Since, $J_x=U.$) So, we can write $U$ as a union of $U$ and an empty set and  this proves the result.
So, was there any necessity to do all these huge line of reasonings? We could have said the same thing, by considering an arbitrary open set $O$ and then note that $O=O\cup \emptyset$ and this would've the result immediately.
Am I missing something?

What they mean for $J_x$ is the maximal open interval that contains $x$. In other words if $x \in I$ for some open interval $I$, then $I \subseteq J_x$.

@ElDorado Well, what do you mean by maximal open interval? The $J_x$ can be $U$ as there's no restriction upon it. $x$ is contained in $U$ and $U$ is open and $J_x\subseteq U$ is the union of all open sets in U that contains $x$ so yes, $J_x=U.$

I can see how confusion arises! The phrasing you reference is not super clear. To answer your question:

Well, won't $J_x$ be precisely equal to $U$?

No: You have that $J_x$ can be created for each $x \in U$, but you do not necessarily have that $J_x = U$. To illustrate this, let us look at a concrete example.
Okay: Suppose $U = (0,1) \cup (3,5)$.
Consider $1/2 \in U$; so we have $J_{1/2} = (0,1)$. Note that $(0,1) \subset U$ but $(0,1) \neq U$.
Similarly, $J_4 = (3,5) \subset U$ but $J_4 \neq U$.
The language may seem a bit tricky; it is not defining e.g. $J_4$ as the union of all open intervals contained in $U$ that contain $4$. Instead, the intention is to consider, e.g. for $x=4$, the union of all open intervals that (1) are entirely contained in $U$ and (2) contain $4$. This cannot be all of $U$ in our example because there is no open interval that contains $4$ and $1/2$ that is contained entirely in $U$: an open interval with $1/2$ and $4$ in it would contain everything between the two numbers. For example, such an open interval would contain the number $2$ since $1/2 < 2 < 4$, but $2 \not\in U$.
There are other open intervals that satisfy both (1) and (2) above; for example, the open interval $(3.75, 4.3)$. This is an open interval that (1) is entirely contained in $U$ and (2) contains $4$. Once you make peace with the two part definition they are giving of $J_x$ for each $x \in U$, you can imagine many open intervals that (1) are entirely contained in $U$ and (2) contain $4$. The biggest such open interval will be $(3,5)$.
